# SSRS Report run automatically

Tags: reporting-services

How do you get a SSRS Report to run automatically when opening?
I want to run, I have parameters but when I have to select run report, but I want it to just run when opened

Answer (score 2):

Every parameter must have a default value. I think it may run automatically then.

Answer (score 1):

> Give every parameter a **default value**.

It will run automatically.
This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255227(v=sql.110).aspx) will help you how to give default values.